# Possible to transfer multiple tokens in one transaction?

Tags: erc-20, transfer

Is it possible to transfer all / multiple ERC20 tokens to another wallet address in a single transaction?

Comment: Yes, by doing all transfers it in a contract function, and then executing that function in a single transaction.

Answer (score 1):

Only from the smart contract based wallets that are designed for this. ERC-20 tokens on normal Ethereum accounts cannot do this.

Comment: Can you provide some links to smart contracted based wallets that can do this?

Comment: https://bulksender.app/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, we've built an automated solution for this which is a [Token MultiSender Dapp](https://blockbucket.io/) with really little fees (0.01 ETH) for each batch transaction.

The UI makes it really simple, feel free to check out the code too :)